# Delegate.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, silverlight

It looks like the C# compiler has some logic embedded in it to detect the presence of Silverlight, by examining the symbols inside mscorlib. When detecting a Silverlight version of mscorlib, it will not emit BeginInvoke and EndInvoke members on any delegate types it generates.

This makes sense, as those methods aren't support on silverlight.

Does anyone know what types / members it uses to trigger that decision (specifically in the delegate case)?

Comment: What is your intended aim? maybe someone can answer more directly to your problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the complete answer... but it looks like my particular problem was caused by a misspelling of `AsyncCallback`. I had it as `AsyncCallBack`. That of course makes sense, because the `BeginInvoke` and `EndInvoke` signature can't be emitted if there is no `AsyncCallback` delegate.